# 'CSSTransition cannot be used as a JSX Component' - Error in Dev but not Prod

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

Project created using React and Typescript.

I'm using  from react-transition-group to handle a small animation when opening/closing a menu. The animation effect seems to function just fine, but on every page load it displays a browser error related to  That says 'CSSTransition cannot be used as a JSX component"

Here is the error message in the browser (same error appears in VS Code when hovering the :

```
'CSSTransition' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'CSSTransition<HTMLElement | undefined>' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2786)
```

For reference, this is the component using the CSS Transition:

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren, useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import './collapsibleSection.scss';
import { ReactComponent as ChevronDown } from '~/assets/icons/chevron_down.svg';
import { FlatButton } from '../flatButton/FlatButton';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

type CollapsibleSectionProps = {
  color: 'blue' | 'yellow';
};

export function CollapsibleSection({ children, color = 'yellow' }: PropsWithChildren<CollapsibleSectionProps>) {
  const [t] = useTranslation();
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <section className={`collapsible-section ${isOpen ? 'collapsible-section--open' : ''}`}>
      <h2>
        <FlatButton
          ariaExpanded={isOpen}
          buttonType={color === 'yellow' ? 'light' : 'dark'}
          onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
          title={t('guide.viewMore')}
        >
          <ChevronDown className="collapsible-section__icon" aria-hidden="true" />
        </FlatButton>
      </h2>
      <CSSTransition in={isOpen} timeout={300} classNames="animation" unmountOnExit>
        <div>{children}</div>
      </CSSTransition>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Like I said, it seems like the animation works fine, but I'd like to resolve the IDE error and browser error if possible. Any suggestions on how to resolve? I've tried updating the react-transition-group package and the type definitions but no luck.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/25580

Answer (score 0):

Consider saving the file as "tsx" instead of "jsx" since it appears that you are utilizing TypeScript.

Comment: Apologies that it wasn't clear from the initial post, but the relevant components are all .tsx files (CollapsibleSection.tsx)